# showing country api info (capital, currency,...) of a world countries dropdown selection in a card container

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, searchbar, countries

I'm trying to show the card info of South Africa as default value (before typing any country's name into the search bar input field or chosing a specific country out of a given list) and the according country info details within the card container! In this context, I'm using the restcountries api with their country json info!
Why is it not working with 'forEach' and maybe you might have any ideas or suggestions how to solve it?

```
    beforeMount() {
        var self = this;
        var found = false;
        this.countries.forEach(function(element) {
          if(element['alpha2Code'] === 'ZA') {
            self.selectCountry(element);
            //self.push(element);
            found = true;
          }
        });      

        if(!found)
            this.selectCountry(this.countries[0]);
    
      },



html:
<main>

  <nav>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="country-search">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search country..." autocomplete="off" v-model="search">
    </div>

    <div class="country-list" id="country-list">

      <div class="country" v-for="(country, index) in countries"  method="GET" @click="selectCountry(country)">
        <img :src="getFlagSrc(country)">
        {{ getName(country).common }}
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <section :style="{ 'background-image': url(' + selectedFlagSrc + ')' }" v-for="(country, index) in filteredCountries" @click="selectCountry(index)">

    <div class="card-container">
      <div class="card">

        <div class="card-title">
          <img :src="selectedFlagSrc.flags.png" alt="" />
        {{ selectedName.common }}
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
          <div><strong>Code: </strong>{{ selectedCode }}</div>
          <div><strong>Capital: </strong>{{ selectedCapital }}</div>
          <div><strong>Region: </strong>{{ selectedSubregion }}</div>
          <div><strong>Language: </strong>{{ selectedLanguage }}</div>
          <div><strong>Currency: </strong>{{ selectedCurrency }}</div>
          <div><strong>Timezone: </strong>{{ selectedTimezone }}</div>
          <div><strong>Population: </strong>{{ selectedPopulation }}</div>
          <div><strong>Area: </strong>{{ selectedArea }}</div>
          <div><strong>World Bank Gini: </strong>{{ selectedGini }}</div>
          <div><strong>Lat Long: </strong><a :href="selectedLatlngUrl" target="_blank">{{ selectedLatlng }}</a></div>
</div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</main>
```

[image]

I hope to solve the issue with the default values!All around the card container on the right one should see the flag of South Africa as default bfore making any choice (respectively afterwards - the given flag of a chosen or country typed into the input field on the left in the picture below)! So far, the info concerning the chosen country haven't been correctly transferred to the card container on the right, unfortunately ;(!

Comment: Please add proper lib/framework tag

Comment: Hi! As I've already got stuck and frustrated I hereby send you my latest code via my codepen.io-workspace: https://codepen.io/PeteFox/pen/zYeGpbQ

Maybe, some of you could help me with this to make any further improvement with e.g. showing the country info also in the card container on the right and chosing South Africa as default value before typing any country into the input field! I'd really appreciate all your efforts and suggestions coming up  ;(!

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to fix your code

There are a lot of problems in your code and there are still more. You really should check it out

### HTML structrue

You've put the card outside of Vue app mounting target (the `div id="app"` inside your html). That's the reason why card only show `{...}`. Also, I have replace `<div  id="app"/>` with `<main id="app"/>` because your CSS made the card overlay and cover the list.

```html
  <main id="app">
    <nav>
      <div class="country-search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search country..." autocomplete="off" v-model="search">
      </div>
      <div class="country-list" id="country-list">
        <div class="country" v-for="(country, index) in filteredCountries" method="GET" @click="selectCountry(country, index)">
          <img :src="getFlagSrc(country)">
          {{ getName(country).common }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <section :style="`{background-image: url('${selectedFlagSrc}')}`">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-title" id="card_title" method="GET" v-if="selectedCountry" v-for="name in selectedCountry.name.common">
            <img :src="selectedFlagSrc" alt="" />
            {{ selectedCountry.name.common }}
          </div>

          <div class="card-body" id="card_body">
            <div><strong>Code: </strong>{{ selectedCode }}</div>
            <div><strong>Capital: </strong>{{ selectedCapital }}</div>
            <div><strong>Region: </strong>{{ selectedSubregion }}</div>
            <div><strong>Language: </strong>{{ selectedLanguage }}</div>
            <div><strong>Currency: </strong>{{ selectedCurrency }}</div>
            <div><strong>Timezone: </strong>{{ selectedTimezone }}</div>
            <div><strong>Population: </strong>{{ selectedPopulation }}</div>
            <div><strong>Area: </strong>{{ selectedArea }}</div>
            <div><strong>World Bank Gini: </strong>{{ selectedGini }}</div>
            <!--<div><strong>Lat Long: </strong><a :href="selectedLatlngUrl" target="_blank">{{ selectedLatlng }}</a></div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Moreover, you didn't close a lot of tags and misplace them. Like how you open `<nav>` before `<div>` but you close `<nav>` before `<div>`

### Computed and hook

First, do not modify `computed` if you didn't declare setter for it. That's the reason why I deleted `countries` and changed it to `data`

Don't put your API call (ajax, fetch) inside computed properties. I've moved all logics inside `computed.countries` into your `mounted`. I also removed your filter mechanism, you'll need to re implement it in side `mounted` because I don't really understand how it worked. This is how your `mounted` look like

```js
mounted() {
    (async () => {
      const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
      let countries = await response.json();
      countries.sort((a, b) => a.name.common.localeCompare(b.name.common));

     this.countries = countries;
      // After mount, pick South Africa as default

      for (let [i, country] of Object.entries(this.countries)) {
        if (country["name"]["common"] === 'South Africa') {
          this.selectCountry(country, i);

          return;
        }
      }

      this.selectCountry(this.countries[0], 0);
    })();
  },
```

I've also delete your `beforeMount` since it didn't do anything because you declared it inside `methods` and you didn't call it

### Properties

You use some undeclared properties in HTML template like `selectedFlagSrc`

### Methods

`selectCountry` require `index` to work. If `index` is null, the line below will fail

```js
self.search = self.filteredCountries[index].name.common;
```

But you use it without providing `index` at `mounted`

```js
this.selectCountry(this.countries[0])
```

---

There are still a lot to check. You should recheck your code before moving any further. Please be patient and coding with care.

Since you coding your Vue application like this, I suggest take a look at Vue document to create a native Vue project. Splitting chunk to component help you debug your code easier

This is the code after fix https://codepen.io/duckstery/pen/vYbmVmZ

Good luck to you

Comment: Thank you very much, duckstery for your efforts and very valuable advice! Yesterday, I obviously was too tired after a few hours of programming and did the mistake with the id=app which I added to the position where it was pretty at the end of the evening! I'll try to work on it as my aim is to become better and improve my programming skills !

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to upload the code link, I've edited my answer. You should check it.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, I was aiming at showing the South African default before mounting - that's why I tried this way ! Do you know why the flag and country's name in the right card container is shown several times also in your code example?

Comment: And the "selectedFlagSrc" is supposed to return the flag url and thereby showing the chosen flag as background image around the card container but it, unfortunately hasn't worked out yet!

Comment: If you want it to showing SA before mounting, you should create `beforeMount` outside of `methods`. It's shown several time because of `v-for` and the way you setup `selectedCountry.name.common`. You should check it out. And for the `selectedFlagSrc`. You should remove the style `background-image`. Then try to set it manually in your `$().animate()` with this line `$("section").css("background-image", "url(" + self.selectedFlagSrc + ")")`

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've managed to solve the background topic, the one with the card container title repetition and could also return the vast majority of the card container values (with a mix of your and my code parts), except for the currencies and languages which are definitely more challenging in the v3.1 of restcountries api and I've to think about in more detail now[image: Argentina's Geodata]
Well, default value of South Africa (beforeMount) and the geodata info for currencies and languages are still missing and to elaborate on!

If anyone of the brain drain here had any suggestions or ideas how to cope with the remaining parts, I'd be more than grateful for any hints ;)!

For those of you who continuously like to train their brain and solve challenging tasks, I hereby provide you with my updated code (see codepen-link below )! As I'm well aware of the fact that it is by far not perfect I'm doing my best to improve and further elaborate on it !

Comment: https://codepen.io/PeteFox/pen/zYeGpbQ